# How to set form input data to equal specific strings in a PHP If Else Statement?

Tags: php, string, forms, if-statement, post

I'm having trouble with this for some reason. Basically i'm trying to make it so that one person can go through. If the users name is equal to "Megan" "Renae" then the output will be Hello, "Megan" "Renae" but if there is anything else I want it to output I do not know you. I know this is probably something extremely simple and it is just going over my head but if someone could help you would stop my hair from turning grey! Thank you in advance to anyone that responds.

```
<form method = "POST" action = " ">
<p>Please enter your first name: <input type="text" name="fName"><br>
<p>Please enter your last name: <input type="text" name="lName"><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="btnSubmit"  name="submit"></p>
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] != "") {
if ($_POST['fName'] = "Megan") {
 if ($_POST['lName'] = "Renae") {
 echo "<p>Hello, Megan Renae</p>"; }
else {
echo "<p>I do not know you</p>";     
}}}
?>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong operator. `=` is to set a value; try `if ($_POST['fName'] == "Megan")` to do a comparison, instead.

Comment: Your using assignment instead of comparison. You'll want to learn AJAX..

Answer (score 1):

This is the PHP snippet you are looking for:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['fName'] == 'Megan' && $_POST['lName'] == 'Renae') {
       echo '<p>Hello, Megan Renae</p>'; 
    }
    else {
        echo '<p>I do not know you</p>';     
    }
?>
```

In the if statements where you have `$_POST[...] = 'some value'` you need to use `==` to compare the values instead of `=` which sets the value of the variable.

Comment: Actually, she is probably getting an error because she didn't check if the post values are set.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes True, yet irrelevant. 99% of the problem are the operators.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It has a relevancy since she will always get an error in her original code when verifying if submit equals empty string.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Always get a "notice" yes but that won't prevent the script from functioning and to check if something is equal to something. C'mon, you know that.

Comment: Yeah I know that. When I made my first comment I hadn't noticed that XD